top right navigation bug
There's something wrong with this site's behaviour. When I click on the icons in the top right, for inbox, achievements, list of other sites, etc, the menu opens for a second and then closes again before I can even click an option.
It doesn't happen in the StackOverflow site.
I cleared all cookies and logged back in. Still the same behaviour.
Same thing also happens now that I want to add tags to this post. I have to be REALLY quick to click on the item I want.
Also, while writing in this post body field, the focus sometimes shifts to some element outside of the field.
